# How to make push and pull when file is over 100mb?

Tags: firebase, react-native, github

I create a `React Native` project include `Firebase` sdk. When I make a command

`git push origin mybranch` show the error about `GoogleMobileAds` file over 100mb on my terminal.

I find the suggestion should remove it, I type command

`git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch ios/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds'` before push.

But when I pull my branch and build my project will show the error is I don't have the file `GoogleMobileAds`.

So I have to download the file from somewhere again, but If I want to push my project, the `100mb error` must happen again.

My question is what is the way to finish the pull and push if I have file over 100mb and don't need to download my file from somewhere again ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure if [Git LFS](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs) could help you here and or if this is worth a read [Why can't Git handle large files and large repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393447/why-cant-git-handle-large-files-and-large-repos)

Comment: Thanks for reply, not very sure Git LFS means, is that I download it then I can push 100mb file to github ?

Comment: You are not supposed to include Pods (or node_modules while we're at it) in your sources. Try adding the Pods folder to your .gitignore file.

Comment: @EugenTimm Thanks for your suggestion, I will try to update gitignore.